# uderstanding the mechanism of Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I'm using keycloak, but I don't understand how the verification of authentication is made after the user authenticate in the app.
For example I have an app secured with keycloak, when a user try to access it, he/she will be redirected to authentication page, then (I guess, and correct me If I'm wrong) the user will  have a token that need to be send with every request.

Comment: Not every requests, the next one, for redirection from login page, and in your application you validate the token and you open a session that not depends of keycloak. After that your user is authenticated and it use the technology of the application. If you use stateless REST endpoint it could be that you need to add the token in every requests.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On a complete system secured with Keycloak:

1. A user clicks from a public page to navigate to a protected area within the application. The link to this protected area is in your application settings in keycloak admin console.
2. The user will be redirected indeed to the Keycloak authentication page. After providing Username and password, Keycloak redirects the user back to your application again with a code that is valid to a very short period of time.
3. The application communicates this code to Keycloak along with the Application ID and the Application secret, then Keycloak replies with the Access token, ID token, and a Refresh token. your Application will need only one of these tokens to see which claims the user has, and according to the claims, the user will be granted or denied access to protected URL(s)

Answer (score 1):

Authorization code/standard flow:

1. From your app you're redirected to Keycloak's login page.
2. You give your username and password to Keycloak, and if these are correct, you will get a redirection to your app, and get an authorization code.
3. Your app send this auth_code and its id and secret to keycloak, and keycloak give you a token.

There are two more flows: resource owner credentials, and client credentials.

Comment: thank you for responding.this is the respond that I need, to verified that I get the idea here is what I understand :  the resource owner (**RO**) while interacting with a **client** (let say browser) that need  to access a **secured app (SA)** will be redirected to **keycloak server**  so that **RO** gives his credentials, if those are correct,then it will be (the **client** ) redirected to the **SA** and get an authorization code that the **client** will sent to **keycloak** server with other data, to get a token, then with every request the **client** will use the token